# How to get the path or name of the process from pid in linux

Tags: linux, signals

I have implemented a `sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL)` signal handler from which I am able to get the pid of the process which is sending the signal. And with this pid I am trying to get the path of that process using the command

```
ls -l /proc/pid/exe
```

but it is showing message

```
ls: /proc/23710/exe: No such file or directory
```

Even I am executing the command "ps" the process is not listed. Can anybody tell me how to get the path or name of such process?

Comment: You're running `ls` from a signal handler? That won't end well.

Comment: Show us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. Perhaps your inspection of `si_pid` is wrong. Perhaps instead the signaling process is reaped by the time you check, but a coding error seems more likely.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the command line of the process from pid, you can read the `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`:

```
   /proc/[pid]/cmdline
          This read-only file holds the complete command line for the
          process, unless the process is a zombie.  In the latter case,
          there is nothing in this file: that is, a read on this file
          will return 0 characters.  The command-line arguments appear
          in this file as a set of strings separated by null bytes
          ('\0'), with a further null byte after the last string.
```

From that, you may get the path or name of the process.